# Nested Form not rendering or saving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I'm new to Ruby and also Rails, and I'm trying to put together a nested form that ultimately creates a page but also allows the user to create individual parts **inline** before submitting the page. The inline form contains two buttons, one adds a part and the other one removes it. Here are my relevant files (please let me know if you need to see any other) and I'll list the problems I'm having after:

FYI, the gems I'm using are: [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/), [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) and Bootstrap. On Rails 4.

_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for(@page, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f|

  = f.input :title, label: 'Title'
  = f.input :description, label: 'Desc'

  .form-group
    .col-xs-10
      label Parts
      .form-inline
        = f.simple_fields_for :parts do |part|
          = render 'part_fields', f: part
        .links
          = link_to_add_association 'Add Part', f, :parts

  = f.button :submit
```

_parts_fields.html.slim

```
= f.input :part_type, collection: ['String 1', 'String 2'], prompt: 'Part type', label: false
= f.input :part_title, placeholder: 'Part title', label: false
= f.input :part_desc, placeholder: 'Part description', label: false
= link_to_remove_association 'Remove Part', f
```

/models/page.rb

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    has_many :parts
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts
end
```

/models/part.rb

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :page
end
```

/controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @pages = Page.all

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
            format.json { render json: @pages }
        end
    end

    def new
        @page = Page.new

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
            format.json { render json: @page }
        end
    end

    def edit
        @page = Page.find(params['id'])
    end

    def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @page.save
                format.html { redirect_to(@page) }
                format.json { render json: @page, status: :created, location: @page }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
  end

  def update
    @page = Page.find(params['id'])

        respond_to do |format|
            if @page.update_attributes(page_params)
                format.html { redirect_to(action: 'index') }
                format.json { head :ok }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'edit' }
                format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
  end

    def page_params
        params.require(:page).permit(:title, :description, parts_attributes: [:id, :part_type, :part_title, :part_desc])
    end
end # End Pages Controller
```

Routes

```
resources :projects do
    resources :pages
end

resources :pages

resources :parts
```

**Problems:**

1) The form is not saving any data (can't edit/update current pages or create new ones). **Update**: fixed, see my own answer below.

2) On the partial I'm using a `collection` to have a dropdown menu, but those test values are hard-coded right now. How can I have a dropdown that populates each field with columns from the db?

3) The inline form elements which come from the partial are not being rendered back on the main form. All I see is the "Parts" label and no elements underneath it. **Update**: `@pages.parts.build` solved this.

Appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Comment: In your controller try `@page.parts.build` to add a new part instance to the parts collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is now saving data as expected. In one of my partials I had two fields that were identical and thus creating a silent conflict for me. In addition, after I resolved this I started to get an `Unpermitted parameter: _destroy` error, and the fix was to add `:_destroy` to the list of required params for `parts_attributes`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a `@page` object with no `parts`. So when it tries to render the `fields_for`, it does! Just, zero times. Add `@page.parts.build` in your controller to add one.
2. Not sure; too tired right now. Try changing `save` to `save!` and `update_attributes` to `update!` so Rails throws an error instead of failing silently. BTW, why do you have `if params[:page]` inside your `page_params`? That isn't needed; that's what `require(:page)` does.
3. ActiveRecord provides a [column_names](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Base/column_names/class) method, that returns an array of column names.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Ryan and apologies for the late response. I have to read up on the `build` method to fully understand the details behind what it does, but that did solve that part of my problem, so thank you. The form is still not saving - I'm using `save!` and `update!` now but no errors are being logged; in fact I see the same exact output on the terminal when updating a record. Any ideas what could be doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `@page.parts.build` will always build a new `part`, even if the user did not request this (it could be what you want). Now you only show the `Add` button for each nested part. I would assume you would want only one `Add` button, as follows:

```
  .form-inline
    = f.simple_fields_for :parts do |part|
      = render 'parts_fields', f: part
      = link_to_add_association 'Remove Part', f, :parts            
    = link_to_add_association 'Add Part', f, :parts
```

This will always show the `Add Part` link (and only once).

As to not saving, possible reasons are:

- the data is not posted to the server (check your logfile, possible reasons are errors in your html, e.g. multiple identical ids)
- the data is blocked by your strong-parameters command
- the data is blocked by the `reject_if` condition of the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`
- a failed validation

Now, if the code displayed is your actual code everything seems ok. So could you show us what is posted to the server? (check your logfile).

Comment: Nathan thank you for taking the time to reach out! I actually just figured out why the form wasn't saving (I'll make a post about it). I updated the form + partial in the OP; the idea is for the user to have only one Add Part in the entire form, and one Remove Part next to each part added. Here's an image. Question: a part is always built by default as you said, how can I change this so the user must add even the 1st one?